# Failed on uploading high sized videos to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm developing a web application using angular and firebase. Additionally, I want my users to be able to upload big videos to firebase.

But the problem is that when I try to upload videos bigger than 10485760 bytes I'm getting the following error:

```
angular.js:13294 Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains a string greater than 10485760 utf8 bytes in property 'posts.-KDiuigtRhbVxoAocPBb.source' ('data:video/quicktime;base64,AAAAFGZ0eXBxdCAgAAAAAH...')
```

Is there any work around here so I can make it possible?

---

What I have pretty much now:

**.html**

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    <input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera" id="file-upload">
</span>
<div class="field button">
    <button ng-click="createPost()" ng-hide="createMode">Post</button>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.createPost = function() {
    if ($scope.postVideoData) {
      $scope.post.createdAt = new Date().toString();
      $scope.post.source = $scope.postVideoData;
      $scope.post.sourceType = "VIDEO";
    }
    $publisherServices.create($scope.post, user);
    $location.path("/" + $routeParams.associate);
  };
```

**$publisherServices**

```
.service('$publisherServices', function($firebaseArray, FBURL, $sharedProperties, $location, $routeParams) {

  var ref = new Firebase(FBURL).child("posts");
  var posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
  return {
    all: posts,
    create: function(post, user) {
      post.ownedBy = $sharedProperties.getCurrentAssociate().$id;
      post.postedBy = user.uid;
      //Add to firebase db
      return posts.$add(post);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using a cloud storage service like Amazon S3? If Firebase is reasonably setting a 10GB limit, I doubt there is a way to store them in Firebase. Instead, you can just store them in the cloud and store a link to the videos in Firebase.

Comment: @SunilD. Actually, its only 10MB limit. :/

Comment: Oops, don't know what I was thinking, a 10GB limit would be way too high :) I store the videos for my app in S3, their pricing is very reasonable. You can use their free tier for a year too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation on limitations and restrictions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html):

> Size of one child value
>
> Limit: 10mb (UTF-8 encoded)

You're getting an error that says that you're exceeding that limit. There is no way to change that limit, for *very* good reasons.

Storing large media files in the Firebase Realtime Database is a bad idea. It is not meant to be a media storage layer, but a database for synchronizing reasonably sized data in real-time.

For storing media files, use a dedicated service (S3, GCS, whatever) and then use Firebase to store and communicate the URL.